# how to show specific parameters from another menu's model in the form view? ( Odoo 13 Enterprise)

Tags: view, module, odoo, formview, odoo-13

I'd used the studio tool to make a menu: (Bảo Hiểm Xã Hội) with submenu: (Hồ Sơ), (Điều Chỉnh), (Lịch Sử)
[image]

In submenu: (Điều Chỉnh). I created the default value.
[image]

Then in the FORM VIEW of submenu: (Hồ Sơ), I want to show the default value from submenu: (Điều Chỉnh) by using many2one.
[image]

But it just shows FALSE in the selection box.

So... how to show the specific parameter from the submenu: (Điều Chỉnh)?

Please help. Thank You!

Comment: how was the `many2one` defined?

Comment: I just drag and drop many2one field and choosing relation from the submenu: (Điều Chỉnh).

Answer (score 0):

i believe that problem is you Odoo showing `x_name` field. I don't know how to change that in studio. Maybe make it related field to the desired field.

Comment: If I use a related field then it cannot be a selection. But when using a default field like an employee field, It can show all the default employees for choosing.

Comment: in Điều Chỉnh `x_name` not on Bảo Hiểm